# Cannot convert input string to Int64 in ASP.NET using store procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have used the store procedure in MS-Sql for inserting for particular page it is working fine but I also need the same store procedure for other page it is finding me the error.

```
protected void btnsubmitt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList arParameters = ReturnParameter();
    DataSet dsInsertProfile = objadmin.GetGridData(arParameters,                    objconstant.sSP_INSERT_PROFILE);

    if (int.Parse(dsInsertProfile.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString()) == 0)
    {
        pnlProfile.Visible = false;
        pnlThank.Visible = true;
        lblThank.Text = "Your profile have been successfully saved.";
    }

    else
    {
        lblThank.Text = "Your profile is not saved, please try again later.";
    }

}
public ArrayList ReturnParameter()
{
    Int64 email = Convert.ToInt64(txtemail.Text.ToString());
    ArrayList arSample = new ArrayList();
    Object[] c_email_id = new Object[3] { "@strEmailID", "varchar", email};
     arSample.Add(c_email_id);
     return arSample;
}
  public DataSet GetGridData(ArrayList dbArray, string sSpName)
    {
        DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();
        dsDataSet = datamanager.GetGridData(dbArray, sSpName);
        return dsDataSet;
    }
    public static DataSet GetGridData(ArrayList dbArray, string sSpName)
    {
        DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection cn = createConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = sSpName;

        object objPrMtrName;
        object objSqlType;
        object objPrMtrVal;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dbArray.Count; i++)
        {
            objPrMtrName = ((object[])(dbArray[i]))[0];
            objSqlType = ((object[])(dbArray[i]))[1];
            objPrMtrVal = ((object[])(dbArray[i]))[2];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(objPrMtrName.ToString(), GetSqlDataType(objSqlType.ToString())).Value = objPrMtrVal;
        }
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dsDataSet);
            return dsDataSet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Mystore procedure

```sql
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spInsert_profile]
(  @strEmailID varchar(200)

)
 AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intEmail INT
SET @intEmail = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gdt_Users WHERE [c_email_id]=@strEmailID)        
IF @intEmail = 0
 BEGIN

       Insert into gdt_Users([c_email_id],[d_modified_dttm],[d_created_dttm])values(@strEmailID,GETDATE(),GETDATE())

 SELECT @intEmail
  END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @intEmail

    END
END
```

Here, I was facing a problem. It was throwing an exception

```
ERROR: Failed to convert parameter value from string to Int64
```

So, I've add this code

```cs
Int64 email = Convert.ToInt64(txtemail.Text.ToString());
```

in arraylist `returnparameter()` method. Then, it threw that exception

```
ERROR: Input string was not in correct format
```

How can I solve this? Can you help me?

Comment: What you are passing in txtemail.Text

Comment: yes., you want to check the `txtemail` text values, You need to pass the "Numbers" only to that text-box..!!

Comment: @Jodha i am passing an email id i.e., like nirmalahb1@gmail.com

Comment: Are you passing numbers to field [c_email_id]/ @strEmailID

Comment: @Ravia No, i am not passing any integers in emailid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I can find Convert.ToInt64 only at one place which is

```
Int64 email = Convert.ToInt64(txtemail.Text.ToString());
```

You would not be passing valid number to Convert.ToInt64( as `txtemail` will have string not a number. You should give a number in txtemail or use the correct textbox for converting the string to int64.

> Keep in mind Convert.ToInt64( converts string to number only if the
>   string is number.

Comment: ok.let us verify about for example take name oly instead email which involves oly characters then also i get error "Failed to convert parameter value from string to Int64 "  without converting to INT64 code..how can i solve this

Comment: There will be problem with procedure. Do not call the procedure and check if you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure expects `varchar(200)` which is equivalent to `String` of length 200, so email should be string and not number. E.g. yourname@someemail.com is a string. Am just curious, what makes you think is `int64`. It should be

```
string email = txtemail.Text;
```

Your code down here indicates `email` should be string by using `"varchar"`

```
string email = txtemail.Text; //change your code to this
ArrayList arSample = new ArrayList();
Object[] c_email_id = new Object[3] { "@strEmailID", "varchar", email};
```

Comment: eventhough i use only string then also i am getting same error.

Comment: what's your `GetSqlDataType` returning for `"varchar"`?